# android - how to display the array of object from Cloud FireStore in the RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display the data that I stored in the Cloud Firestore to a RecyclerView but when I run the application it displays all except the `itemList` only the `map` is being displayed

I don't receive any error so it leads me to a bottleneck

[image]

[image]

**the code for my adapter**

```
    Context context;
    List<ViewOrderModel> viewOrderModelList;

    public ViewOrderAdapter(Context context, List<ViewOrderModel> viewOrderModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.viewOrderModelList = viewOrderModelList;
    }

   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewOrderAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.userName.setText(viewOrderModelList.get(position).getUserName());
        holder.date.setText(viewOrderModelList.get(position).getCurrentTime());
        holder.totalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(viewOrderModelList.get(position).getTotalPrice()));
        holder.address.setText(viewOrderModelList.get(position).getAddress());
        holder.phone.setText(viewOrderModelList.get(position).getPhoneNumber());

        ViewOrderModel viewOrderModel = viewOrderModelList.get(position);
        holder.productName.setText(viewOrderModel.getProductName());
        holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(viewOrderModel.getTotalQuantity()));

    }
```

**Model Class**

```
public class ViewOrderModel implements Serializable {

    String userName,phoneNumber,currentTime,address,documentID,productName;
    long totalPrice;
    List<ViewOrderModel> itemList;
    int totalQuantity;
```

**Main Activity**

```
        order_rec = findViewById(R.id.admin_view_order_rec);
        order_rec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
        viewOrderModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        viewOrderAdapter = new ViewOrderAdapter(this,viewOrderModelList);
        order_rec.setAdapter(viewOrderAdapter);
        firestore.collection("UserOrder")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                            List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                            for (DocumentSnapshot docSnap : list) {
                                ViewOrderModel orderModel = docSnap.toObject(ViewOrderModel.class);
                                viewOrderModelList.add(orderModel);
                            }
                            viewOrderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Is there a way to display the data or any other way different for what I'm doing in my codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to two different classes. The first one would be, for example, `ViewOrderModel` class, which will hold the fields as `address`, `currentTime`, `documentID`, and so on.

And the second one called `Product`:

```
class Product {
    String documentID, productName;
    int productPrice, totalPrice, totalQuantity;
}
```

Which will hold the properties corresponding to the object that exists in the `itemList`. So your `ViewOrderModel` class should look like this:

```
public class ViewOrderModel implements Serializable {
    String userName,phoneNumber,currentTime,address,documentID,productName;
    List<Product> itemList;
            
}
```

Comment: I did the answer you gave it gave me this when i run my application `com.example.chocolate_republic.models.OrderProduct@dfce294, com.example.chocolate_republic.models.OrderProduct@42dc13d, com.example.chocolate_republic.models.OrderProduct@a8a0d32, com.example.chocolate_republic.models.OrderProduct@3790a83`
I don't know what this is

Comment: You have two options, you either override toString and provide another implementation or you create another adapter for reading all those objects.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a clue from both option you gave me, Is there a possible reference that I can look up?

Comment: To display the products in `itemList`  you have to do the same operation you already did. So you have to create another adapter and use a `List<Product> productList;` and display each product object. If you only want the size of the list for example, there is no need for any adapters.